Martingale problem for the Wiener process
Consider $\Omega \triangleq \mathbf{C}([0,T];\mathbb{R})$, $\mathbf{F} \triangleq \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{C}[0,T];\mathbb{R})$ (Borelian $\sigma$-algebra) and $\mathbf{F}_t \triangleq \sigma \left \{ W_s, \: 0 \leq s \leq t \right \}$ (the filtration associated with the projection) where $W_t(\omega) = \omega(t)$.
The problem is to find a measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega, \mathbf{F})$ such that

$\mu \left ( \left \{ \omega \in \Omega, \: \omega(0)=0 \right \} \right ) = 1$, and
$\forall f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ twice continuously differentiable with compact support, $\forall n, \: \forall 0 \leq r_1 \leq \cdots \leq r_n \leq s \leq t \leq T$ and $g_1, \cdots, g_n$ continuous bounded functions
$$
\int_{\Omega} \left \{ f(\omega(t)) - f(\omega(s)) - \frac{1}{2} \int_s^t f''(\omega(r)) d r \right\} \prod \limits_{i=1}^n g_i(\omega(r_i)) d \mu(\omega) = 0. 
$$
The second point is saying that
$$
M_t^f \triangleq f(W_t) - f(W_0) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(W_s) d s
$$
is a martingale under the measure $\mu$.
How do we show that the Wiener measure is the unique solution to this problem without using Ito's lemma? We know how to evaluate the Wiener measure on cylinders but how to go beyond? It seems to me that the difficulty comes from the term
$$
\int_s^t f''(\omega(r)) d r.
$$

